# Would this be considered polymorphic?

Tags: java, polymorphism

I've written this code and as part of the requirements, I must use polymorphism. I was wondering if this would be considered to be polymorphic?

runAnimation is a method in the Animation class that prints the image onto the screen, this code is in a different class altogether.

Thanks in advance.

```
Animation dragon1;
Animation dragon2;


dragon1 = new Animation(5, tex.dragon1[0], tex.dragon1[1], tex.dragon1[2], tex.dragon1[3]);
dragon2 = new Animation(5, tex.dragon2[0], tex.dragon2[1], tex.dragon2[2], tex.dragon2[3]);

dragon1.runAnimation();
dragon2.runAnimation();
```

Comment: What is polymorphism? Answer that, then answer your question.

Comment: Does the Animation class extend off of any other class?

Comment: polymorphism is based on the substitution principle. I'm guessing that it is because Animation in my case can take many forms, and therefore so can runAnimation. That would make this polymorphic?

Comment: I can't see anything polymorphic here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Polymorphism, in Java, refers to subclasses of a class which share many of the same methods (defined in the parent), but which implement (override) a method that makes it unique to the subclass.  You have just made two objects from the same class (Animation).

You might want to search for polymorphism in Java (here is a [response from the language tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html)).

Here is a crude example:

```
public class Mammal {
    private String name;
    public Mammal(String aName) { name = aName; }
    public String getName() { return name;}
    public int getLegs() {return 4; }
    public int getHands() {return 0;}
}

public class FourFootedMammel extends Mammal {
    public FourFootedMammel(String aName) {super(aName);}
}

public class TwoFootedMammal extends Mammal {
    public TwoFootedMammal(String aName) {super(aName); }
    public int getHands() {return 2;}
    public int getLegs() {return 2; }
}   

TwoFootedMammal human = new TwoFootedMammal("Human");
FourFootedMammal dog = new FourFootedMannal("Dog");
```

Comment: Ahhh thanks, I understand it much better now I see what i did wrong and will change it.